# Background image is not visible using before property in css

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navigation::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/200/200');
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Register</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add a background image to my content but it is not appearing using the 'before' property in navigation as.... .navigation::before{image code for background}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems which each, independently, cause the problem you are seeing. You need to fix both of these.

## Negative z-index

You gave `::before` a negative z-index, which puts it **under** the `.navigation` element's content. The black background colour covers up the `::before` element so you can't see it.

## Zero dimensions

You haven't set the `height` and `width`, not have you used `position: absolute` in combination with `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` so the size of `::before` is based on its content.

The content of `::before` is an empty string, so no size at all is needed to display that, so it gets rendered `0px` by `0px`.

There are no pixels in which the image is rendered.

You need to give it a size somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  --nav-height: 2rem;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: var(--nav-height);
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation li {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.navigation::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/200/200');
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--nav-height);
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Register</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```